# Unusual behaviour when iterating a copy of a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, flask

Example : Passing `test` to print it in the template using Flask and Jinja.

```
@app.route('/mypage')
def mypage():        
    # just open the json file and read it...    
    input_file  = file(FILE, "r")
    j = json.loads(input_file.read().decode("utf-8-sig"))
    for item in j[:]:
        test = "test"       

    return render_template('mypage.html', j=j, test = test, config = {'environment_args':{'autoescape':False}})
```

Notice `j[:]`

And now when I want to print it in the HTML file :

```
<p>{{test}}</p>
```

the result is :

```
None
```

Update : This is a sample of the json file :

```
[
    {
        "trailers": {
            "quicktime": [], 
            "youtube": [
                {
                    "source": "FZCxSiYRh7Q", 
                    "type": "Trailer", 
                    "name": "Trailer 1", 
                    "size": "Standard"
                }
            ], 
            "id": 54315
        }, 
        "date": "2008", 
        "genres": [
            {
                "id": 18, 
                "name": "Drame"
            }
        ], 
        "tagline": "", 
        "popularity": 0.23, 
        "vote_count": 2, 
        "start": "Monday 09 December 01:10", 
        "length": "95", 
        "overview": "", 
        "vote_average": 10.0, 
    }, 

    {etc}
]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example JSON snippet that lets you reproduce this error?

Comment: @SeanVieira I added a, example :-)

Comment: @4m1nh4j1 what is the `test = 'test'` supposed to be doing in that loop anyway? I take it, it works if you just pass `test='test'` straight to the template? Otherwise, I'd expect a `NameError` if `j` had no elements... So puzzled why you get `None`... The "iterating over a copy of a list" is a red herring here

Comment: I used to read elements from `j` and create other elements like `var = int(item['vote_average'])` and then `return render_template("page.html", j=j, var=var)`

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you show seems to have an error-- the comma after the final number.  The below is an example that works for me:

```
#app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def mypage():
    # just open the json file and read it...
    input_file = file('file.json', "r")
    j = json.loads(input_file.read().decode("utf-8-sig"))
    for item in j[:]:
        print item
        test = "test"

    return render_template('index.html', j=j, test=test, config={'environment_args': {'autoescape': False}})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

An example HTML template, rendering both you test variable, and also iterating through your JSON structure to print each start date:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
    <body>
        {{ test }}
        {% for row in j %}
            <li>{{ row.start }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

And just for completeness-- the JSON file I used.

```
[
    {
        "trailers": {
            "quicktime": [],
            "youtube": [
                {
                    "source": "FZCxSiYRh7Q",
                    "type": "Trailer",
                    "name": "Trailer 1",
                    "size": "Standard"
                }
            ],
            "id": 54315
        },
        "date": "2008",
        "genres": [
            {
                "id": 18,
                "name": "Drame"
            }
        ],
        "tagline": "",
        "popularity": 0.23,
        "vote_count": 2,
        "start": "Monday 09 December 01:10",
        "length": "95",
        "overview": "",
        "vote_average": 10.0
    }
]
```